# Unclear error when I try to reverse dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code:

```
my_dict = {'Anthony Hopkins': ' Hannibal, The Edge, Meet Joe Black, Proof', 'Julia Roberts': ' Pretty Woman, Oceans Eleven, Runaway Bride', 'Salma Hayek': ' Desperado, Wild Wild West', 'Gwyneth Paltrow': ' Shakespeare in Love, Bounce, Proof', 'Meg Ryan': ' You have got mail, Sleepless in Seattle', 'Russell Crowe': ' Gladiator, A Beautiful Mind, Cinderella Man, American Gangster' .....}

dictrev={}

for i in mydict:
    for j in mydict[i] :
        if j not in dictrev:
           dictrev.setdefault(j, []).append(i)
print (dictrev)
```

The problem is that when I debug I saw that the program reads only one character values (this line `for j in mydict[i] :` and I need the first value (there are multiple values).

Any suggestions what is the problem
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - please provide examples of what your output is and exactly what you expected

Comment: `for j in mydict[i]` will iterate over whatever value is associated with the key `i`. If this value is a string, it will iterate over it one character at a time. What do you want it to do? Also, you will probably have a problem with `newdict.setdefault(v, []).append(k)` because you don't declare `k` or `v` in the code you show. Please show all relevant code.

Comment: Provide an example of `mydict`, `dictrev`, as well as your expected output.

Comment: What's your `mydict` content?

Comment: this is mydict {'Anthony Hopkins': ' Hannibal, The Edge, Meet Joe Black, Proof', 'Julia Roberts': ' Pretty Woman, Oceans Eleven, Runaway Bride', 'Salma Hayek': ' Desperado, Wild Wild West', 'Gwyneth Paltrow': ' Shakespeare in Love, Bounce, Proof', 'Meg Ryan': ' You have got mail, Sleepless in Seattle', 'Russell Crowe': ' Gladiator, A Beautiful Mind, Cinderella Man, American Gangster' .....}
dictrev={}

Comment: @josh Please add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

Could you please format your code like this:

```
do whatever
```

You do that by typing enter two times, then for each line of code indenting four spaces. To type normally after that, start a new line and do not type the four spaces at the start of it.

If I understand what you are asking, you want to swap the key and value of the dictionary, and you are getting an error while doing so. I cannot read your unformatted code (no offense), so I will provide a dictionary swapping technique that works for me.

```
my_dict = {1: "bob", 2: "bill", 3: "rob"}
new_dict = {}

for key in my_dict:
    new_key = my_dict[key]
    new_value = key
    new_dict.update({new_key:new_value})

print(new_dict)
```

This code works by having the original dictionary, `my_dict` and the uncompleted reversed dictionary, `new_dict`. It iterates through `my_dict`, which only provides the key, and using that key, it finds the value. The value that we want to be a key is assigned to `new_key` and the key that we want to be a value is assigned to `new_value`. It then updates the reversed dictionary with the new key/value. The final line prints the new, reversed dictionary. If you want to set `my_dict` to the reversed dict, use `my_dict = new_dict`. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in the comments, the values in your `dict` are strings, thus iterating over them will produce single characters. Split them into the desired tokens and it will work:

```
dictrev={}  # movie: actors-list  (I assume)

for k in mydict:
    for v in mydict[k].split(', '):  # iterate through the comma-separated titles
        dictrev.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the reverse your dictionary values (separated by commas), the following may be the solution that you're looking for:

```
my_dict = {
    'Anthony Hopkins': ' Hannibal, The Edge, Meet Joe Black, Proof',
    'Julia Roberts' : ' Pretty Woman, Oceans Eleven, Runaway Bride'
}
res_dict {}

for item in my_dict:
    res_dict[item] = ', '.join(reversed(my_dict[item].strip().split(','))).strip()
```

[`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) used to remove spaces at the beginning / end of each value

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) used to split values (using `,` separator)

[`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) used to reverse the resulted list

[`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) used to form the final value for each key of `res_dict`

**Output:**

```
>>> res_dict
{'Anthony Hopkins': 'Proof,  Meet Joe Black,  The Edge, Hannibal', 'Julia Roberts': 'Runaway Bride,  Oceans Eleven, Pretty Woman'}
```